# Trying to draw on a canvas with sliders

Tags: java

I am attempting to use jsliders to allow a user to pinpoint the origin of a circle to be drawn on a canvas. I am using a button to show and hide the circle. I am using paint on an inner jpanel so that paint will not write over components. However, the coordinates inside the jpanel are different than the coordinates for the entire frame. So, it is very difficult for me to get the coordinates of the jslider and then translate it to the jpanel to draw the circle. Is there an easy way to figure this out without a ton of guess and check? I am also using the custom layout miglayout. I have included the code for my GUI class as well as my custom JPanel I made so I could mess with the paint method.

```
public class CircleGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
    private CustomPanel innerpanel;
    private JSlider x,y;
    private JColorChooser colorpick;
    private JButton state;
    private boolean bstate;

CircleGUI()  {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize()  {
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    bstate = false;

    x = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,650,325);
    x.setPaintTicks(true);
    x.setPaintLabels(true);
    x.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650,0));

    y = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,650,325);
    y.setPaintTicks(true);
    y.setPaintLabels(true);
    y.setInverted(true);
    y.setOrientation(JSlider.VERTICAL);
    y.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (0,600));

    colorpick = new JColorChooser();
    state = new JButton("Show");
    state.addActionListener(e -> {
        if(!bstate) {
            int positionx = x.getValue() - 80;
            int positiony = y.getValue();
            Color c = colorpick.getColor();
            innerpanel.setColor(c);
            innerpanel.setX(positionx);
            innerpanel.setY(positiony);
            innerpanel.repaint();
            state.setText("Hide");
            bstate = true;
        } else {
            Color transparent = new Color(0,0,0,0);
            innerpanel.setColor(transparent);
            innerpanel.repaint();
            state.setText("Show");
            bstate = false;
        }
    });
    JPanel outerpanel = new JPanel(layout);
    innerpanel = new CustomPanel();
    innerpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    innerpanel.setBorder(blackline);
    outerpanel.add(x,"wrap");
    outerpanel.add(y,"split 2");
    outerpanel.add(innerpanel);
    outerpanel.add(state,"wrap");
    outerpanel.add(colorpick);
    
    this.setSize(1000, 1000);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.add(outerpanel);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

}



public class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    private Color c;
    private int x;
    private int y;

public CustomPanel() {
    c = null;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {

}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(c);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
}

public void setColor(Color c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use variables x/y and and methods setX() and setY(). The JPanel class has  `getX()` and get `getY()` methods which are used to set the location of the component relative to its parent. So it can be confusing. Use variables like ovalY/ovalY and corresponding setter methods to avoid confusion.  *I am also using the custom layout miglayout* - can't test your code to see what is happening. Code posted in the forum should use standard classes so the code can be tested.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. Yes, the x/y coordinates of the panel will be different than the frame. I would expect the slider values to be relative to the panel, not the frame. So why is this an issue? You can't paint at (0, 0) relative to the frame, only (0, 0) relative to the panel. Don't try to adjust the x value. Just paint at the location specified by the slider. Also, I'm not sure what the point of using a transparent color is. You won't be able to see anything.

Comment: The innerPanel.repaint() method should be invoked in the setOvalX() and setOvalY() methods. It is the responsibility of the component to repaint itself when a proper is changed. The application should not invoke repaint() directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are trying to make a one-to-one mapping between the value of the `JSlider` and the coordinate in your `CustomPanel`. You should use the `JSlider` value as a percentage, i.e. minimum value zero and maximum value 100. If you want the circle to appear in the middle of the `CustomPanel` so you place both `JSlider`s in their mid-points, i.e. both at 50%. Then you calculate 50% of the corresponding dimension to get the coordinate. If the width of `CustomPanel` is 600, then 50% of 600 is 300 so `positionx` needs to be 300.

The only thing I changed in your code is the calculation of `positionx` and `positiony`.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class CircleGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
    private CustomPanel innerpanel;
    private JSlider x,y;
    private JColorChooser colorpick;
    private JButton state;
    private boolean bstate;

    CircleGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        bstate = false;

//        x = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 650, 325);
        x = new JSlider(0, 100, 10);
        x.setPaintTicks(true);
        x.setPaintLabels(true);
        x.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 0));

//        y = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 650, 325);
        y = new JSlider(0, 100, 10);
        y.setPaintTicks(true);
        y.setPaintLabels(true);
        y.setInverted(true);
        y.setOrientation(JSlider.VERTICAL);
        y.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 600));

        colorpick = new JColorChooser();
        state = new JButton("Show");
        state.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (!bstate) {
                int positionx = Math.round(x.getValue() / 100.0f * innerpanel.getSize().width) - 50;
                int positiony = Math.round(y.getValue() / 100.0f * innerpanel.getSize().height) - 50;
                Color c = colorpick.getColor();
                innerpanel.setColor(c);
                innerpanel.setX(positionx);
                innerpanel.setY(positiony);
                innerpanel.repaint();
                state.setText("Hide");
                bstate = true;
            }
            else {
                Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
                innerpanel.setColor(transparent);
                innerpanel.repaint();
                state.setText("Show");
                bstate = false;
            }
        });
        JPanel outerpanel = new JPanel(layout);
        innerpanel = new CustomPanel();
        innerpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        innerpanel.setBorder(blackline);
        outerpanel.add(x, "wrap");
        outerpanel.add(y, "split 2");
        outerpanel.add(innerpanel);
        outerpanel.add(state, "wrap");
        outerpanel.add(colorpick);

        this.setSize(1000, 1000);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(outerpanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            CircleGUI cg = new CircleGUI();
            cg.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Color c;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public CustomPanel() {
        c = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(c);
        g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
    }

    public void setColor(Color c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even realize I could do it that way. I appreciate the help and what I am trying to achieve works well now